# Powershell bulk rename file name including ()

Tags: powershell

Files are named like 20160825().xlsx

Have tried both of this without any changes to the file names

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\..." -Filter “*()*” -Recurse | Rename-Item NewName {$_.name -replace ‘()’,’’ } 

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\..." -Filter “*()*” -Recurse | Rename-Item -LiteralPath -NewName {$_.name -replace ‘()’,’’ }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-replace` uses regular expressions (regex), which is a different language with different rules, and parentheses are special characters for grouping, and they need to be escaped to match literally. Try:

```
$_.name -replace '\(\)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may let PowerShell/.net do the escaping:

```
$RE = [RegEx]::escape("()")
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\..." -Filter "*()*" -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item NewName {$_.Name -Replace $RE}
```

BTW I'd avoid using an editor which replaces quotes with typographic ones.